# LaTeX math mode and mbox mode

Tags: latex, tex

According to a doc I found around

> An \mbox within math mode does not use
>   the current math font; rather it uses
>   the typeface of the surrounding
>   running text.

In math mode, I would like to write something like a_{\mbox{foo}}. If I use this, the foo will be quite big, too big. If I write a_{foo}, foo will be in italic.

What is the magic trick to have non-italic, small text?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I personally prefer to use the `\text{}` command provided by the [AMS-LaTeX package](http://www.ams.org/tex/amslatex.html).  To use this, you need to include the statement

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

somewhere in your document preamble, and then in any mathematical environment,

```
a_{\text{foo}}
```

will produce the desired output.  Section 6 of the [User’s Guide for the amsmath Package](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf) mentions that the `\mbox{}` equivalent is

```
a_{\mbox{\scriptsize foo}}
```

A final option is

```
a_{\mathrm{foo}}
```

which is what I used before I discovered AMS-LaTeX and the `\text{}` command.

Answer (score 2):

I usually use the option `a_{\rm foo}` since this is the shortest form I am aware of. I'm not sure if there are any caveats though. I guess the proper form is using the form `a_{\text{foo}}` suggested by las3rjock

Answer (score 2):

You can use the similar commands `\mathmbox` or `\mathmakebox` provided by the [`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package.

Answer (score 1):

You can just type `a_{\text{foo}}`

I did not try, but it should work

EDIT: as las3rjock said, the `\text{.}` is provided by the AMS-LaTeX package. So you need to add the `\usepackage{amsmath}`

Comment: \text{} is a command provided by the AMS-LaTeX package, so it will not work if you don't have the statement "\usepackage{amsmath}" somewhere in your document preamble.

Comment: Or `\usepackage{amstext}` if you don't want amsmath (for some reason).